# Set oneof in a protobuf message using reflection

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

After a few hours, I still can not set a `oneof` field in a clear (just created) protobuf message using reflection in c++.

I can obtain the needed [OneOfDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#OneofDescriptor) through the [Descriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#Descriptor) of the message. But when I try to 'set' the oneof using [Reflection](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Reflection), I found the real problem. There is only three function members related to [OneOfDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#OneofDescriptor):

- [HasOneOf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Reflection.HasOneof.details) to check if there is a previous defined `oneof` in the message
- [GetOneofFieldDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Reflection.GetOneofFieldDescriptor.details) to get a [FieldDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#FieldDescriptor) from a previous defined `oneof` in the message
- ClearOneof (without documentation) to clear `oneof`.

So there is not a `SetOneofFieldDescriptor`and if the `oneof` in the message is not previously defined, using a `mutable_XXXX` function member in the message, the `GetOneofFieldDescriptor` returns `nullptr`.

Therefore I am really stuck and any idea will be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set it the same way you would set the field if it weren't part of a `oneof`.  Get a `FieldDescriptor` from the message's `Descriptor` and pass it to the appropriate `SetXXX` method of the message's `Reflection`.

Given a message like the following:

```
message Foo
{
    oneof bar
    {
        int32 a = 1;
        string b = 2;
    }
}
```

You can set the `a` member as follows:

```
#include "foo.pb.h"

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    const google::protobuf::Descriptor* d = f.GetDescriptor();
    const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* a = d->FindFieldByName("a");

    const google::protobuf::Reflection* r = f.GetReflection();
    r->SetInt32(&f, a, 42);
}
```

Protobuf will take care of making sure any previously set members of the `oneof` get unset as needed.